# mysql - get the average of the output average

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table. `final`,`milestone` and `milestonewp` consider that the three tables is foreigned key like `milestonewp`<--FK--`milestone`<--FK--`Final` .Then I have a `column` for determining the average of the `milestonewp` for a certain foreign key. Then getting that average to be average again to be displayed to the `final` table.
Here is my visual representation

```
milestonewp
condition | mile_id
20          1
20          1
30          1
21          2
21          2
31          2
40          3
30          3
50          3
```

How can I average the  average that the chart above will produce?
I'm trying to work on this

```
select avg(milewp_condition)
from logs_pms_r_milestone_wp
where mile_id=1;
```

but i dont have any idea how it can produce for the other `mile_id`

**EDIT**

The above code will produce something like this

```
avg(milewp_condition)
0
0
0
```

so then, i also want to average that 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well this should be what you look for:

```
SELECT AVG(milewp_condition)
FROM logs_pms_r_milestone_wp
GROUP BY mile_id;
```

If you want to average all, just do:

```
SELECT AVG(milewp_condition)
FROM logs_pms_r_milestone_wp;
```

Regards

Comment: hey, thanks, it sorts out. But how can I get the result of that to average again?

Comment: That just average all of the rows. I'm saying how can i get the output of milestone_wp so that i can average them again. You're first statement is correct, yes. How can I average them again?

Comment: Averaging on what? Could you give me a better view of the structure of the tables and on what you want to make the average?